# Array loop variable ecx(-1)

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly

I want to count the numbers that are 0.
MASM Error:

> loop variable `ecx`(-1).

Using ollydb.

Help please. Why didn't it work?

```
.586
        .model flat, stdcall

        extern ExitProcess@4:near

        includelib c:\masm32\lib\user32.lib
        includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib


        data segment
            mas db 1,0,9,8,0,7,8,0,2,0
            rez db 0
        data ends


        text segment
        start:
            mov cx, 10
            xor ax, ax
            xor si, si
            jcxz exit

            cycl:
                cmp mas[si], 0
                jne m1
                inc al

                m1:
                    inc si
                    loop cycl

                mov rez,al

            exit:
                push 0
                call ExitProcess@4
        text ends
        end start
```

Comment: from that includelib i guess you are running it on windows. using 16 bit registers in 32 or 64 bit mode is always bad idea, read documentation of loop instruction in 32 bit mode -> it uses ecx not cx, reading from [si] will probably generate PME unless you are in ring 0

Comment: This is a 32-bit program. Don't use 16-bit registers without a good reason. Therefore change at least all cx to ecx and all si to esi.

Comment: `loop` uses ECX in 32-bit mode (not CX), but that shouldn't stop it from assembling.  (This code seems like a terrible idea in 32-bit mode, though.  A 16-bit addressing mode probably can't address static data.  And you don't zero the upper 16 bits of ECX so the loop could run very many iterations).  But it sounds like you're saying you got an error message from MASM when trying to assemble, so there was no executable to run under ollydbg.  Isn't there a line number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're programming for 32-bit!
The `LOOP` instruction will use the `ECX` register, **but you only initialized the `CX` register**. That produces the error.

```
start:
    mov ecx, 10
    mov al, 0
    xor esi, esi
cycl:
    cmp mas[esi], 0
    jne m1
    inc al
m1:
    inc esi
    loop cycl
    mov rez,al
```

Comment: But why does that stop it from *assembling* with MASM?  All of the instructions in the OP's program are valid in 32-bit mode.  They don't create a useful program as a whole, but that's the programmer's problem.  Assemblers don't normally stop you from emitting the machine code you write, or at most warn.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't believe it was an assembly time error. I blame it on poor wording by the OP. Probably ollydb showed `ECX==-1`.

Comment: That's impossible.  Starting with `ECX = 0x????000a`, the loop will stop at 0 (if it doesn't fault first).  You can only get ECX = -1 if you run `loop` with ECX=0.

Comment: True. But can we be sure that it was the `loop` instruction that stopped the program? If it stopped for some other reason with the debugger showing `ECX == 0x????FFFF`, and considering that the OP doesn't care too much about `CX` vs `ECX`, it could hint why the OP wrote "ecx(-1)". Don't know really...